Is it possible to create a large array in C?
I have 16GB of RAM and this code
#include <stdio.h>
#define len 900000000

int phi[len];

int main() {
  for (int i = 2; i < len; i++) {
    phi[i] = i - 1;
  }
  phi[0] = 0;
  phi[1] = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 2 * i; j < len; j += i) {
      phi[j] -= phi[i];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

this code does not compile
error: unknown type size

Is there anything that can be done to make it compile without rewriting the code? I work on Windows 10.

The problem is in the compiler. I used the Tiny C Compiler, I haven't been able to test the others on my machine yet, online compilers don't have this problem. And in Windows 10 I can allocate 4 GB of memory.
I can compile with #define len 500000000 but it won't work. I get the following error message:

This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check the software publisher.



"Make it compile without rewriting the code" might be a really bad idea, even if possible.  Are you ok with having a 15.6GB .exe file?

If the compiler does not support objects of sufficient size, you can try calling malloc or VirtualAlloc instead. However, I am not sure if this is what you want, since you stated in the question that "rewriting the code" was not what you want.

@Ben Voigt, Nah. Being initialized with zeroes, it will be placed in BSS segment which isn't actually stored in the executable.

First thing to try is knock a few zeroes of the end of len until it does compile and tell us which compiler and version you are actually using. The limitation is almost certainly in the compiler not the C language. What do you hope to achieve by running this code?


Is it possible to create a large array in C?

I was almost able to do it on
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
Compiler: x86_64-pc-cygwin, gcc version 12.4.0 (GCC)
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

//#define len 900000000
#define len   (90000000L*5)


int phi[len];

int main() {
  printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) SIZE_MAX);
  printf("%d\n", INT_MAX);
  printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long) len);
  assert(len < INT_MAX);
  for (int i = 2; i < len; i++) {
    phi[i] = i - 1;
  }
  phi[0] = 0;
  phi[1] = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 2 * i; j < len; j += i) {
      phi[j] -= phi[i];
    }
  }
  clock_t t = clock();
  printf("Time: %g\n", (double) t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}

Output with 90000000*5
18446744073709551615
2147483647
270000000
Time: 204.546  

At 90000000*6, it was too large for my machine/compiler.

@Lundin "90000000 * 5 = 4.510^9. INT_MAX = 2.110^9. That's a beginner level bug of integer overflow" --> My calculation indicates 90000000 * 5 = 4.5*10^8.  The code assert(len < INT_MAX) checks for that beginner level bug.  Updated to used a wider type to help avoid overflow in 90000000*5 should we have a 28-bit int.

@EugeneSh. "answer as well as the question lack the details about the compiler used" --> OP added compiler used, as does this updated answer.

I have never used Tiny C Compiler, but I can write the following:
Some compilers limit the maximum size of an object. The ISO C standard only requires that the compiler supports object sizes of at least 65535 bytes, but most modern compilers support significantly larger objects.
In your posted code, assuming that sizeof(int) == 4, the array phi has a size of 3.6 gigabytes when you declare it with 900,000,000 elements. When you declare it with 500,000,000 elements, it still has a size of 2 gigabytes. Based on the error messages you posted, my guess is that the compiler you are using does not support objects of that size.
One thing that you could try is to use dynamic memory allocation instead, by calling the function malloc:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int *phi = malloc( 900*1000*1000 * sizeof(int) );
    if ( phi == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf( "The memory was successfully allocated.\n" );

    free( phi );
}

Alternatively, you could try calling the Windows API function VirtualAlloc directly, instead of doing this via malloc. I don't know whether this is possible using the Tiny C compiler.
